# using tell me to mean 'what is it?'

Tags: grammar, subcontinental-english, non-standard

It seems to be a common practice in India to respond to someone's call by saying *tell me*. It's used even in calls; the conversation goes something like this:

> Me: Hello
>   Caller : Hello
>   Me: Who's this?
>   Caller: Ram (Some old friend)...
>   Me : Yeah Ram, Tell me...

Is this correct English??

Comment: What @Mamta said. It seems to be a (non-standard) Indian English usage, approximately corresponding to ***Talk to me*** as used by some native speakers in similar contexts. Except the native speaker version is usually somewhat rude / imperious, whereas I doubt the IE version is seen that way (if anything, it would *lower* the relative status of the speaker, since it clearly indicates that he doesn't speak *standard* English).

Comment: @MamtaD That question is related, but it seems to be asking specifically what's acceptable in a professional context, not informal conversations between friends.

Comment: What do you mean by _it's used even in calls_? As opposed to what else? The first sentence said that you're just talking about calls.